# boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket -> how to query the socket state?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I am using the boost library to create a server application. At a time one client is allowed therefore if the async_accept(...) function gets called the acceptor will be closed.

The only job of my server is to send data periodically (if sending is enabled on the server, otherwise "just sit there" until it gets enabled) to the client. Therefore I have a boost message queue - if a message arrives the send() is called on the socket.

My problem is that I cannot tell if the client is still listening. Normally you would not care, by the next transmission the send would yield an error.

But in my case the acceptor is not opened when a socket is opened. If the socket gets in the CLOSE_WAIT state I have to close it and open the acceptor again so that the client can connect again.

Waiting until the next send is also no option since it is possible that the sending is disabled therefore my server would be stuck.

Question:
How can I determine if a boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket is in a CLOSE_WAIT state?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use ip::tcp::socket::get_option and get error state with level SOL_SOCKET and option name SO_ERROR. I'm surprised that I have not found the ready boost implementation for it. So you can try to meet GettableSocketOption requirements an use ip::tcp::socket::get_option to fetch the socket error state.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to do what Dmitry Poroh suggests:

```
typedef asio::detail::socket_option::integer<ASIO_OS_DEF(SOL_SOCKET),SO_ERROR>so_error;
so_error tmp;
your_socket.get_option(tmp);
int value=tmp.value();
//do something with value.
```